rounding to nearst 0 or 5 in gtsummary outputbale
I need help in rounding the last digit to 0 or 5 in my gtsummary output table. any help is much appreciated
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

data %>% 
tbl_summary(
  by = hba1c,
  include = -id
) 

here is data
structure(list(id = 1:100, age = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", 
"b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", 
"a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c"), sex = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F"), country = c("eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", 
"wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", 
"wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", 
"eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", 
"eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", 
"scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", 
"scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", 
"scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", 
"wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", 
"wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", 
"eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", 
"eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", 
"scot"), edu = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", 
"x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", 
"y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", 
"x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", 
"y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z"
), hba1c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))


You can create your own styling function to do this.
round_05 <- function(x) {
  ceiling(x/5) * 5
} 

And then use it in your tbl_summary call to round the frequencies while keeping the percentages as is. If you want to round the percentages too, then create another similar function that multiplies x by 100 first and replace the "0" with this function.
df %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = hba1c,
    include = -id,
    digits=list(everything() ~ c(round_05, 0))
    # digits=list(everything() ~ c(round_05, round_pct))
  )




thanks for your help. it worked. just want to clarify if I want add_n to my code and also want my rounding off here in this too, so how should i modify this code df %>%
tbl_summary(
by = hba1c,
include = -id,
digits=list(everything() ~ c(round_05, 0))
# digits=list(everything() ~ c(round_05, round_pct))
) %>%
add_n()

That should work. But note that rounding the n's to 0 or 5 will almost certainly result in those totals not adding to the total "N".

thanks for your reply. it didn't work.

Try this: df %>% tbl_summary(by=hba1c, include=-id, digits=list(everything() ~ c(round_05, 0))) %>% add_n()

thanks, sorry i was not clear enough. the rounding works for hb1c= 0 and hba1c =1 but rounding didn't work for column n i.e add_n()

AFAICT, add_n() doesn't allow a styling function.

is there a way to fix this?

I think you should try asking that in another question.

thank i'll do it. just wanted to ask how can i add a comma separator in my numbers format in this summary output as i have quite a big number

In the round_05 function, change to: prettyNum(ceiling(x/5) * 5, big.mark = ",")

@ Edward thanks it worked
